# Python Tkinter Sequential Forms Passing Parameters

Tags: python, tkinter, parameter-passing

I am new to Python programming, and am a bit stumped on a problem.

I am **trying to build a sequence of forms and pass parameters from one form to the next**. Although I have found examples showing how to switch between forms, I have not found an example that shows passing parameters between forms in different classes.

The code below is bad and has errors--sorry about that. I assume this is a relatively easy for an experienced Python programmer to answer. I appreciate your help and consideration in in this matter.

```
# Problem 1: All forms open at once instead of 1 at a time
#         2: The buttons are not attached to the forms
#         3: Not sure if parameters are being passed from Form1 to Form2
#         4: Now i am getting errors
# Notes: All forms will be different sizes

import tkinter as tk

class Form1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        two=tk.Tk() # <--define object for Form2
        value1 = 'Some Text'
        value2 = 8
        value3 = 'More Text'
        #--attempting to pass 3 parameters to Form2
        #---on click, open Form2  and close Form1
        self.btn=tk.Button(self,text='button 1',
                           command=Form2.__init__(two, value1, value2, value3))
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

class Form2(tk.Tk):
   def  __init__(self, parm1, parm2, parm3):
        print(parm1, parm2, parm3)

        three=tk.Tk() # <--define object for Form3
        #---on click, open Form3 form and close Form2
        self.btn=tk.Button(self,text='button 2', command=Form3.__init__(three))
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

class Form3(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        three = tk.Tk()
        self.btn=tk.Button(self,text='button3 ',command=None) # action to be added later
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

a=tk.Tk()
Form1 = Form1(a)
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop). Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who took the time to post comments. After more research, I re-wrote the program. It works now.

```
# Working Example of how to pass parameters to sequential windows

import tkinter as tk


class Win1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()        

        rownum = 0
        colnum = 0
        #-----collect some information needed for the application--------------------------
        self.lbl_a = tk.Label(self, text="Number of Categories", font=("Arial Bold", 10),
                                       justify="left",anchor='w')
        self.lbl_a.grid(column=colnum, row=rownum,columnspan=1,sticky='w')
        self.numcat_ent =tk.Entry(self, width=12,background='white',
                         fg='blue',state='normal',font=("Arial Bold", 10), justify='center')
        self.numcat_ent.insert('end', '4')
        self.numcat_ent.grid(column=colnum+1, row=rownum)
        numcat=int(self.numcat_ent.get())

        rownum += 1        
        self.lbl_b = tk.Label(self, text="Items Per Category", font=("Arial Bold", 10),
                                       justify="left",anchor='w')
        self.lbl_b.grid(column=colnum, row=rownum,columnspan=1,sticky='w')

        items=6
        self.numitems_ent=tk.Entry(self, width=12,background='white',
                         fg='blue',state='normal',font=("Arial Bold", 10), justify='center')
        self.numitems_ent.insert('end', '4')
        self.numitems_ent.grid(column=colnum+1, row=rownum)
        numitems=int(self.numitems_ent.get())

        rownum += 1
        #---on click, open Win2  and close Win1
        btn1=tk.Button(self,text='Show Win 2',
                            command=lambda: self.open_win2(master,numcat ,numitems))

        btn1.grid(row=rownum,column=colnum,sticky='nsew')
    def open_win2(self, master, numcat ,numitems):
        self.hide(master)
        self.root2 = tk.Toplevel()
        self.root2.geometry('300x600')
        print(numcat,numitems)
        app2 = Win2(self.root2,root, numcat, numitems)

    def hide(self,master):
        root.withdraw()
        #---to bring root window back
        #root.deiconify()


class Win2(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self, master, root2, parm1, parm2):        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        print(parm1, parm2)
        root.withdraw()
        self.grid()        
        #---on click, open Win3 form and close Win2        
        self.btn1=tk.Button(self,text='Open Win3', command=lambda: self.open_win3(master))
        self.btn1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        rownum = 0
        colnum = 0
        fontSize = 12
        for i in range(parm1):
            rownum += 1
            self.catEntry=tk.Entry(self, width=12,background='white',
                                     fg='blue',state='normal',font=("Arial Bold", fontSize), justify='center')
            self.catEntry.grid(column=colnum, row=rownum)                
            for j in range(parm2):
                rownum += 1
                self.subcatEntry=tk.Entry(self, width=12,background='white',
                                 fg='black',state='normal',font=("Arial Bold", fontSize), justify='center')
                self.subcatEntry.grid(column=colnum+1, row=rownum)                


    def open_win3(self,master):
        self.hide(master)
        root3 = tk.Toplevel()
        root3.geometry('800x800')
        app3 = Win3(root3)

    def hide(self,master):
        root.withdraw()
        master.withdraw()

class Win3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):        
        root.withdraw()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.btn=tk.Button(self,text='Return to Start Page',command=lambda:self.return_to_start(master))
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def return_to_start(self, master):
        master.withdraw()
        root.deiconify()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("225x100")
app = Win1(root)

#----Mainloop keeps forms updated and listens for user input--
root.mainloop()
```